# Getting certain attributes based on other attributes in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

Here's the XML I'm working with:

```
<order xmlns="http://example.com/schemas/1.0">
  <link type="application/xml" rel="http://example.com/rel/self" href="https://example.com/orders/1631"/>
  <link type="application/xml" rel="http://example.com/rel/order/history" href="http://example.com/orders/1631/history"/>
  <link type="application/xml" rel="http://example.com/rel/order/transition/release" href="https://example.com/orders/1631/release"/>
  <link type="application/xml" rel="http://example.com/rel/order/transition/cancel" href="https://example.com/orders/1631/cancel"/>
  <state>hold</state>
  <order-number>123-456-789</order-number>
  <survey-title>Testing</survey-title>
  <survey-url>http://example.com/s/123456</survey-url>
  <number-of-questions>6</number-of-questions>
  <number-of-completes>100</number-of-completes>
  <target-group>
    <country>
      <id>US</id>
      <name>United States</name>
    </country>
    <min-age>15</min-age>
  </target-group>
  <quote>319.00</quote>
  <currency>USD</currency>
</order>
```

What I need to do is get the `href` attribute, from the `link` that has a `rel` of `http://example.com/rel/order/transition/release`

So, how can I do that using Nokogiri?

Comment: You need to show us the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem. See "[ask]". This helps us work in the context of your code instead of create an unrelated snippet that you have to try to force into your code. Also, without the code example it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you which wouldn't be cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy-peasy:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<order xmlns="http://example.com/schemas/1.0">
  <link type="application/xml" rel="http://example.com/rel/self" href="https://example.com/orders/1631"/>
  <link type="application/xml" rel="http://example.com/rel/order/history" href="http://example.com/orders/1631/history"/>
  <link type="application/xml" rel="http://example.com/rel/order/transition/release" href="https://example.com/orders/1631/release"/>
  <link type="application/xml" rel="http://example.com/rel/order/transition/cancel" href="https://example.com/orders/1631/cancel"/>
  <state>hold</state>
  <order-number>123-456-789</order-number>
  <survey-title>Testing</survey-title>
  <survey-url>http://example.com/s/123456</survey-url>
  <number-of-questions>6</number-of-questions>
  <number-of-completes>100</number-of-completes>
  <target-group>
    <country>
      <id>US</id>
      <name>United States</name>
    </country>
    <min-age>15</min-age>
  </target-group>
  <quote>319.00</quote>
  <currency>USD</currency>
</order>
EOT

href = doc.at('link[rel="http://example.com/rel/order/transition/release"]')['href']
=> "https://example.com/orders/1631/release"
```

This is using Nokogiri's ability to use CSS accessors. Sometimes it's easier (or the only way) to use XPath, but I prefer CSS because they tend to be more readable.

[`Nokogiri::Node.at`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at) can take a CSS accessor or XPath, and will return the first node matching that pattern. If you need to iterate over all the matches, use [`search`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-search) instead, which returns a [`NodeSet`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html), which you can treat as an array. Nokogiri also supports `at_xpath` and `at_css` along with `css` and `xpath` for `at` and `search` symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

That's a one-liner:

```
@doc.xpath('//xmlns:link[@rel = "http://example.com/rel/order/transition/release"]').attr('href')
```

Comment: Be careful. Nokogiri's `xpath` returns a NodeSet, which is effectively an array. Taking `attr` from an array will not give you the result you expect if more than one node matches the search. For instance, remove the string match for `rel`, and only look for `@rel`. You'll get the first result found. It's better to use an `at` search, or to specify which element of the NodeSet you want, using Array indexing.

Comment: Correct. I assumed the xml provided was canonical. For a generic solution, yours is the one to refer to.